# Use multiple monitors as one big monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, gui, monitor

So I have multiple monitors to use, I know they can be used in mirror mode where they both essentially display the same thing, or multi monitor mode where they behave like two separate displays side by side.

Now, is there a way to have them act like one big continuous display? For example, can I have two 1920x1080 monitors connected as one big 3840x1080 display and basically be able to have windows spanning both of them?

Unfortunately, googling yields only results about normal multi monitor use.

Comment: You haven't said what OS/release you are talking about, but I use my 1920x10180 displays as if single display with the mouse moving from one to the other, or have a single window spread across both displays (I don't like that though; the black borders on my monitors are annoying) and windows are dragged to use both displays (not maximize as one - though some wm/de's will treat it as a single display with regards maximize; but I didn't personally like that either)

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. And those wms that can treat it like a single display regarding maximize for example would be a nice solution, can you name those?

Comment: Some monitors are quite fancy and have almost no visible block borders :)

Answer (score 1):

xrandr is the utility to produce the display layout that you want.

```
xrandr --output "DP-1-1" --mode "3840x2160" --output "DP-1-2" --right-of "DP-1-1" # launch a window manager   
vim # vim spans both monitors if you only have a single window
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Settings/Devices/Display  and you should see the dual monitor setup.  If you don't select "mirror", you can arrange the monitor icons to attach the way you want for your one big display.

---

I do not understand why you can't do what you want to accomplish with the display setup.  Move the second monitor rectangle's left edge to the right edge of the first monitor rectangle, and you have your 3840x1080 display across the two. Stretch your vim window across the two if you want.  I usually attach the top and bottom, so I have a taller virtual  display, but that's because the netbook display can fit under the external monitor at its full height.

Comment: That's not what my question means, this is still two separate monitors, in the sense that I can for example have firefox on one and vim on the other. What my questions means is treat them like one big monitor with just vim spanning both, for example.